# How to extract different variations of file name in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Say I have these files in my folder below `mydir`

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt.mdgg
```

I want to get file name with full path, file name only and file name without path and .txt extension. For this I tried, but doesn't seem to work. Can someone please suggest me what is wrong with my code?

```
mydir="/home/path"



for file in "${mydir}/"*.txt; do
    # full path to txt
    mdlocation="${file}"
    echo ${mdlocation}
    #file name of txt (without path)
    filename="$(basename -- "$file")"
    echo ${filename}
    #file name of txt file (without path and .txt extension)
    base="$(echo "$filename" | cut -f 1 -d '.')"
    echo ${base}
done
```

Comment: Which part works and which not?

Comment: @Cyrus I am not getting anything for `mdlocation="${file}"
    echo ${mdlocation}`

Comment: you can use `echo \`realpath ${file}\`` to get absolute path for first case.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, assuming `$mydir` is a full path,

```
for file in "$mydir/"*.txt    # full path to each txt
do echo "$file"                
   filename="${file##*/}"     # file name without path
   echo "${filename}"
   base="${filename%.txt}"    # file name without path or .txt extension
   echo "${base}"
done
```

c.f. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *.txt; do
# full path to txt
realpath ${file}
#file name of txt (without path)
echo ${file}
#file name of txt file (without path and .txt extension)
base="$(echo "$file" | cut -f 1 -d '.')"
echo ${base}
done
```

Comment: echo \`realpath ${file}\` Is a useless use of echo. Why not `echo $(echo $(echo $(realpath $file)))`? Just `realpath $file`. Please do not use \` backticks - use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use arrays, and [P.E.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) parameter expansion, without any external tools/utility from the shell.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mydir=/home/path

files=("$mydir/"*.txt)


filenames=("${files[@]##*/}")
pathnames=("${files[@]%/*}")
filenames_no_ext=("${filenames[@]%.txt}")

printf '%s\n' "${pathnames[@]}"
printf '%s\n' "${filenames[@]}"
printf '%s\n' "${filenames_no_ext[@]}"
```

- If you need to loop through the arrays, to do some other things, then do so, since arrays are iterable.